# How to send request body from controller and receive in server using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using AngularJs I send `req.body` form controller to server and get `req.body` but I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'CHKPWD' of undefined

Code:

```
var checkuserpassword = 123;
var CurrentPWD = 123;

$http.post('/Header/ChangeCheckPassword', {
    'CHKPWD': checkuserpassword ,
    'CURRENTPWD':CurrentPWD
}).then(function (response) {});
```

Server

```
exports.postcheckpwd = (req, res) => {

    var checkuserpwd = req.body.CHKPWD;
    var currentpassword= req.body.CURRENTPWD;

console.log(checkuserpwd );
console.log(currentpassword);
}
```

Comment: @Upal any suggestion

Comment: use `=` instead of `:` on server side

Comment: same error came again @pro.mean

Comment: This error means, `req.body` is undefined .. Make sure you have initialized body-parser in your server script

Comment: use `console.log()` function to check the structure of `req` then get the value of `CHKPWD` from the correct property.

Comment: still it's not coming it's shows undefined @ananth

Comment: Do you have something like `app.use(bodyParser.json())` in your server script?

Comment: yes,but i have schema in spreate page